# ¿Qué forma es 'érase' y por qué lleva tilde?

Tags: etimología, acentuación

He encontrado las palabras 'Érase una vez' a los inicios de un libro. Comprendo su sentido pero no su origen. Googleando he descubrido que es una forma de 'ser'. Parece un poco como un subjuntivo pasado. Tampoco comprendo la origen de la tilde.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretérito imperfecto del indicativo «era» + pronombre enclítico de 3.ª persona «se» (uso arcaico: actualmente solo es común ponerlo en infinitivo, gerundio e imperativo).

Lleva tilde porque es esdrújula y todas las esdrújulas llevan tilde.

Se dice «érase una vez» porque es simplemente una expresión lexicalizada.

Comment: Para mejor aclarar el asunto yo diría que "una expresión lexicalizada" es lo que vulgarmente se llama "una frase hecha".

Answer (score 2):

"Érase una vez" es la forma española de la expresión inglesa *once upon a time*, como imagino que ya sabrás. [La respuesta de Paco](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23994/12637) es acertada, pero dado que es una pregunta de etimología me gustaría ver hasta dónde llega la expresión, así que abro el CORDE y me pongo a buscar, dando de bruces con el Quijote:

> *—Pero, con todo eso, yo me esforzaré a decir una historia que, si la acierto a contar y no me van a la mano, es la mejor de las historias; y estéme vuestra merced atento, que ya comienzo. "Érase que se era, el bien que viniere para todos sea, y el mal, para quien lo fuere a buscar..."*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha", 1605 (España).

Se conserva aquí la palabra *érase* como inicio de la expresión, aunque en este caso en su forma "érase que se era", que era otra forma de iniciar los cuentos, con el mismo significado. También se puede usar por sí sola y significaría "there existed":

> *Érase un hombre a una nariz pegado
>
>   érase una nariz superlativa,
>
>   érase una alquitara medio viva,
>
>   érase un peje espada mal barbado; [...]*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "Poesías", 1597-1645 (España).

Nos cuentan en otros textos sus orígenes:

> *"Erase que era" estas son unas palabras antiguas de que las comadres viejas usaban quando juntas a las noches en invierno al fuego por pasar tiempo se contaban unas a otras quentos que llamaban consejas.*
>
> Sebastián de Horozco, "Libro de los proverbios glosados", 1570-1579 (España).

La forma al parecer se usaba ya en el siglo XIV, por entonces no eran raros los textos que usaban el pronombre enclítico tras el verbo de forma habitual (negritas mías):

> *& que era Nabuchodonosor el Rey qui la auie a hermar. & que el nis le podrie tener en campo. nin **amparatsele** en fortaleza que en egypto ouiesse. & **erase** ydo ell estonçes a tierra de los barbaros a so suegro.*
>
> Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Cuarta parte.", c1280 (España).

No es de extrañar pues que los cuentos por entonces comenzaran así:

> *Érase un caçador, muy sotil paxarero,
>
>   fue senbrar cañamones en un viçioso ero,
>
>   para fazer sus cuerdas e sus lazos el redero;
>
>   andava el abutarda çerca en el sendero.*
>
> Juan Ruiz (Arcipreste de Hita), "Libro de buen amor", 1330-1343 (España).

Si la forma *érase* ha perdurado hasta nuestros días es, sencillamente, por ese sabor añejo que da al inicio de los cuentos, como indicando que lo que se va a contar fue algo que sucedió hace mucho, mucho tiempo.